# Check if any of uploaded files in files array is bigger than 256mb

Tags: php, arrays, file

I need to check if any file in `$_FILES` array is bigger than `256mb`. If it were JavaScript, I would use `array.some()`, but in PHP there is no such function.

```
if ($_FILES['upload-file']['size'][0] > 256000000 && $_FILES['upload-file']['size'][1] > 256000000 && ...) {
    $errors['size'] = "Файл превышает максимальный размер. Попробуйте сжать файл или загрузить его в Google Drive.";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out using foreach.

```
foreach($_FILES['upload-file']['size'] as $files){
    if($files > 256000000) {
    $errors['size'] = "Файл превышает максимальный размер. Попробуйте сжать файл или загрузить его в Google Drive.";
    }
}
```